# Closing a Java ConfirmDialog with yes or no option upon clicking yes

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am making a small game of noughts & crosses, and after 5 turns a confirmdialog pops up asking if you want to keep playing or reset the board. The no option resets the board and the yes option makes the confirm dialog close and nothing else happens. I've got the No option done but dont know how to do the yes option.

Here's my code for the confirm dialog:

```
int j = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "het wordt waarschijnlijk gelijkspel. toch doorspelen?", "Doorgaan(Y) of stoppen(N)?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(j == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
            {
                buttons[i].setText("");
                buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
                teller = 0;
            }
        }
        if (j == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            // close the confirm dialog and nothing else happens
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description:

> The no option resets the board and the yes option makes the confirm dialog close and *nothing else happens*

So you could just remove the else part which will keep the buttons' states as they are:

```
int j = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "het wordt waarschijnlijk gelijkspel. toch doorspelen?", "Doorgaan(Y) of stoppen(N)?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if(j == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].setText("");
        buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
        teller = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i do this the dialog frame just keeps popping back up again, it wont close. thanks anyways :)